# Does a distribution exist for the inverse-logit transformation of a Normal random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I saw on wikipedia that there exists a distribution for the logistic transformation of a Normal Distribution: [Logit-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution).

However, this is when $Y \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and I want to find:

$$
\text{logit}(Y) = \log\left(\frac{Y}{1-Y}\right)
$$

I am wondering if there exists a transformation on:

$$
\frac{1}{1+e^{-Y}}
$$

instead. Is there a way to derive it? I tried it and it seems the Jacobian is not in a nice closed form. Are there alternative methods? Thanks.

Comment: Note the logistic function maps $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0, 1)$. The inverse, i.e. the logit function you put down here, have the domain on $(0, 1)$ only. And a normal random variable have a support of $\mathbb{R}$ - it has non-zero probability on $\mathbb{R}\setminus(0, 1)$. Please check.

Comment: So you are saying it is not well defined?

Comment: Yes, what do you think if you take log on negative numbers?